# Почему tkinter.Canvas не на всем экране?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, gui

Столкнулся с проблемой, а именно: виджет Canvas библиотеки tkinter не открывается полностью на весь экран.

Вот часть кода :

```
infoCanvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='grey')
buttonCanvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='green')
self.add_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='knopka.gif')
buttonOpenAdmin = tk.Button(buttonCanvas, command=self.openAdminDialog, bd=0, compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_image)
buttonLessons = tk.Button(buttonCanvas, bd=0, compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_image)
buttonBuses = tk.Button(buttonCanvas, bd=0, compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_image)
buttonTrains = tk.Button(buttonCanvas, bd=0, compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_image)

buttonCanvas.create_window(10, 10, window=buttonLessons)

buttonCanvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
infoCanvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

В чем может быть дело? Canvas открывается только на очень маленькой части экрана, а мое приложение должно быть развернуто на весь экран.

Comment: Добавьте скриншот как сейчас, так будет понятнее что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Предположу, что нужно `.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)` тогда будет расширяться автоматически при разворачивании окна.